# How can I set different axes for different plots in gnuplot?

Tags: visualization, gnuplot

I want to plot a few sets of data points on the same x-axis that have different units. How can I set different axes for each incompatible quantity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNUplot has the ability to have 2 x- and 2 y-axes per plot. The additional axes are called x2 and y2. according to [GNUplot.info FAQ](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00068000000000000000)

Here is a [demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/multiaxis.html) of it being used.

Also have a read of `help plot` from within the GNUplot program.